# why mysql returns some rows when it should return null?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

here is structure of `myTable`

```
----------------
|id|info1|info2|
----------------
|0 |abcde|fghij|
|1 |qwert|yuopa|
----------------
```

here is the query I call :

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `id` = 'a'
```

and it returns the first row which is

```
|0 |abcde|fghij|
```

what is happening? normally `id` is an integer but, by mistake I typed it as a string but I still got a result.

Comment: Can you show us the structure of myTable? I'm finding this difficult to replicate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL tries to cast `'a'` as integer. The string does not contain any numeric values, so the result of the cast is `0`. That's just how MySQL does casting.

```
SELECT 0 = 'a';
```

The above query returns `1` (TRUE).

```
SELECT CAST('a' AS SIGNED INTEGER);
```

The above query returns `0`.

Comment: @bluebrain well, there's that. But more importantly, you shouldn't compare ids in the table to strings. This is obviously a logical error in the query.